# PHP multiple arrays to one associative array

Tags: php, arrays, merge, multidimensional-array, associative

How can I merge this three arrays

```
$name ={"Tom", "John", "David"};
$v1 = {"Tom":100, "David":200};
$v2 = {"John":500, "Tom":400};
```

into one multidimensional associative array in two different ways?
One way is the key order should be same as that of array "name".

```
$name_merged_original_order = array (
    "Tom" => Array(
        "v1" => 100,
        "v2" => 400
    ),
    "John" => Array(
        "v1" => "N/A",
        "v2" => 500
    ),
    "David" => Array(
        "v1" => 100,
        "v2" => "N/A"
    )
)
```

Another ways is the alphabetical of array "name":

```
$name_merged_asc = array (
    "David" => Array(
        "v1" => 100,
        "v2" => "N/A"
    ),
    "John" => Array(
        "v1" => "N/A",
        "v2" => 200
    ),
    "Tom" => Array(
        "v1" => 100,
        "v2" => 400
    ),
)
```

The tricky part is that array "v1" and "v2" is not ordered as the key of "name." They also don't have all keys as in "name." Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not tested and the easiest solution:

```
$name_merged_original_order = array();
foreach($name as $key){
    $name_merged_original_order[$key] = array();
    if(array_key_exists($key, $v1)){
        $name_merged_original_order[$key]['v1'] = $v1[$key];
    }
    else{
        $name_merged_original_order[$key]['v1'] = 'N/A';
    }
    if(array_key_exists($key, $v2)){
        $name_merged_original_order[$key]['v2'] = $v2[$key];
    }
    else{
        $name_merged_original_order[$key]['v2'] = 'N/A';
    }
}

sort($name);
$name_merged_asc = array();
foreach($name as $key){
    $name_merged_asc[$key] = array();
    if(array_key_exists($key, $v1)){
        $name_merged_asc[$key]['v1'] = $v1[$key];
    }
    else{
        $name_merged_asc[$key]['v1'] = 'N/A';
    }
    if(array_key_exists($key, $v2)){
        $name_merged_asc[$key]['v2'] = $v2[$key];
    }
    else{
        $name_merged_asc[$key]['v2'] = 'N/A';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your're welcome. It's 6 a.m. here in germany and I bang my head on associative arrays :)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you would like something like that:

```
$name = array("Tom", "John", "David");
$result = array();
$v1 = array("Tom" => "200", "John" => "100", "David" => "10");
$v2 = array("Tom" => "254", "David" => "156");
$vars = array("v1", "v2");
foreach($name as $n)
{
  $result[$n] = array();
  foreach($vars as $v)
  {
    if(array_key_exists($n, ${$v}))
      $result[$n][$v] = ${$v}[$n];
  }
}
```

I hope `$result` is what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's really simple, but I still need "N/A" value if the key doesn't exist. but still great and simple solution!!

Comment: You are welcome! Try add else-statement `else $result[$n][$v] = "N/A";`

Answer (score 1):

For Example, you have these arrays:

```
<?php
$FirstArrays = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$SecArrays = array('1', '2', '3', '4');
```

1)

```
foreach($FirstArrays as $index => $value) {
    echo $FirstArrays[$index].$SecArrays[$index];
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

or 2)

```
for ($index = 0 ; $index < count($FirstArrays); $index ++) {
  echo $FirstArrays[$index] . $SecArrays[$index];
  echo "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume from your comments you only want items that match in all 3 arrays:

```
for( $i=0; $i< count($name) ; $i++){
    if( !empty( $v1[ $name[$i]]) &&  !empty( $v2[ $name[$i]]) ){
       $newArray[$name[$i]]= array( 'v1'=> $v1[ $name[$i]], 'v2'=> $v2[ $name[$i]]):
    }
}
```

To sort:

```
  asort($newArray);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just made the example simple enough. I'd like to learn general methods.